# Is a substring of base64 encoded random_bytes less secure then just using random_bytes

Tags: php, random, encoding

```
$bytes = random_bytes(15);
$encoded = base64_encode($bytes);
$output = substr($encoded, 0, 15);
```

Does this code affect the complexity of the output vs just using

```
$output = random_bytes(15);
```

I think it might because `a` in base64 is `YQ==` and thats more letters
If it does affect it please tell me by how much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 15 random bytes and encode these as base64 you get 20 bytes since base64 encodes 3 bytes into 4 characters. If you then take only the first 15 bytes from the encode 20 bytes you thus use only 3/4 of the original 15 bytes, i.e. 11.25 bytes - or 90 bits. These 90 bits are definitely less  than the original 120 bits (15*8).  How this effects the security depends on your specific (unknown) use case.